# Alternative for Mendeley for Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation

Mendeley is essentially (for me) a software that saves the following data:

- A file
- Tags associated to the file

In practice the files are research papers and the tags are things like author, title etc. Is there any software (preferably open source) that allows one to do the same thing in Ubuntu?

In Mendeley the data is stored online (on their server) and therefore I can access the research papers from any computer. I would prefer if the suggested software could the same thing (but I get to choose where it should be saved). But maybe if I'm only able to store things locally I could be able to simulate access-from-everywhere using Git and a web server?

Comment: Are you looking for a general solution, or one specific to managing a research library of PDFs and generating citations?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. So let me rephrase my question. I want a reasonable way (it may - or may not - use a single software) of being able to save multi-tagged files such that I can: (a) search for a file by tags, (b) being able to access this database from *any* computer and (c) having the freedom of choosing where my files should be saved. "reasonable" and *any* are intentionally vague since I don't want to restrict things too much (and miss out of a good solution). For example *any* could be restricted to "*nix computer", that's fine with me. Sorry for any confusions.

Comment: What I meant by my question is whether you want an answer based ONLY on managing PDf/citations or are you looking for an all-purpose program that will manage all sorts of files (eg docs, PDFs, mp3s, video, etc)? If you only care about PDFs and citation management (ie functional equivalent of mendeley) then some good answers are being provided below.

Comment: Oh, I see! I think I have to say all sorts of files since I'm also saving .djvu, .ps and (rarely) .jpg files.

Comment: Maybe this question is better suited as a "community wiki"?

Comment: you should edit the question to reflect that you want a general answer. Or, perhaps it would it be better to edit the question so that it's specific to reference managers since all of the answers pertain to that, and start a new question that asks for a general answer.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend [Referencer](https://launchpad.net/referencer). You can download it using apt-get. It supports tagging files with fields such as author, title, journal and publisher, etc. For many research papers it will automatically download the data for you provided there is a DOI identifier inside the file. It can also generate BibTex files automatically.

However, it does not store your references online. I use it with git myself, and it works nicely.

Comment: Presumably Dropbox, ubuntu one, or equivalent will also keep things synced between computers and online. I haven't heard of Referencer before (thanks!) -- how nicely does it play with Dropbox?

Comment: It should be fine with Dropbox or anything. It creates a file with all the information inside, so all you need to do is share the file with yourself and open it in the remote instance.

Answer (score 3):

Whay an alternative, when you can use Mendeley.  In comparison, it comes on top.

Try Mendeley Desktop for Ubuntu.  It Save time managing PDFs, instantly share thoughts on papers with colleagues and automatically back up and sync your files between different computers.

To download ans installation instructions visit their [website](http://www.mendeley.com/download-mendeley-desktop/ubuntu).

This has been tested to work on Ubuntu 12.04, 12.10, and 13.04

If you still want an Alternative, try Zotero.

Zotero is a free, easy-to-use Firefox extension or standalone program to help you collect, organize, manage, search and cite your research sources directly in your favourite word processor, with 100 MB free online storage.  To download and installation instriction, visit [Zetero](http://www.zotero.org/).

<sup>Source:[Zotero](http://www.zotero.org/)</sup>

Comment: LOL did you just suggest mendeley as an alternative to itself?

Comment: @amc Why use an alternative when the application is available to Ubuntu.

Comment: I agree that if they want mendeley they should use it. But post specifically asks for an alternative, and my comment asks for clarification about what they want it for.

Comment: I'll also add that I infer from the OP that they want an open source solution. Mendeley is both proprietary and owned by Elsevier.

Comment: @amc I've added an alternative, but I still think use Mendeley Ubuntu Desktop.

Comment: Cool, I was going to suggest that one based on additional info from OP. undownvoted  your answer :)

Comment: Hi Mitch! My biggest issue with Zotero and Mendeley is that the file sync is done through their servers. The issue with this is the restriction of space (unless your are willing to pay) and that I prefer to be in charge of the files (and hence avoid suddenly losing all my files just because some government decided to immediately shut down their services (cf. Megaupload)).

Comment: @droctopus I agree, although Mendeley does give you a generous amount of storage (up to 1GB free -- if you're crafty and make use of groups). I personally use Dropbox to sync my PDF library and I have Mendeley manage it, with BibTeX support enabled (and also synced through Dropbox) so I'll always be able to take my library with me if the time comes and I choose to oc have to leave Mendeley.

Comment: @droctopus Take a look at [Organizing Research Docs with Dropbox and Mendeley](http://ssplab.wordpress.com/2012/09/24/organizing-research-docs-with-dropbox-and-mendeley/).

Answer (score 2):

Do you know Docear? It's open source and has lots of features with regard to PDF management (however, it does not yet support Tags) http://www.docear.org (btw. I am one of the developers).

Comment: The development has stopped in 2018. https://twitter.com/Docear_org/status/1005772247045373952?s=20

Answer (score 1):

[Zotero](https://www.zotero.org/) is an open-source citation manager and has a [plugin](https://www.zotero.org/support/word_processor_plugin_installation) for LibreOffice. It is not currently available from the repositories but the packaging process for it has [started](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/782079). Meanwhile, you can use the `ppa:smathot/cogscinl` [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~smathot/+archive/cogscinl) to install it.

Answer (score 1):

We have developed an open source solution, downloadable from http://www.scientilla.net or from GitHub, that allows users to collaboratively share and refine their scientific bibliographic metadata.

The system relies on a "peer-to-peer" and "open-data" approach as well as on a "clone-and-refine" algorithm. It can import data from external web services.

The more the system is used, the more the information that flows on the network become clean.

Moreover, using Scientilla, any user can obtain the whole metadata shared through the network.